# impala sliding window

Tags: sql, impala, moving-average, sliding-window, sql-timestamp

I would like to run a sliding window function in impala that finds the maximum price based on 5 minutes interval

in other words i want to compare the price of my current row with all rows in the last 5 minutes and write the maximum price

Analytical functions are usually bounded with row numbers, can they bounded by date as well?

```
ID,     Timestamp,          price
1,  2015-04-07 15:43:02,    230
2,  2015-04-07 15:44:04,    205
3,  2015-04-07 15:46:11,    220
4,  2015-04-07 15:48:02,    210
5,  2015-04-07 15:52:09,    200
6,  2015-04-07 15:53:32,    220
7,  2015-04-07 15:54:12,    207
8,  2015-04-07 15:57:33,    218
9,  2015-04-07 15:61:26,    221
10, 2015-04-07 15:61:01,    210
```

expected output:

```
ID,     Timestamp,          price, Max(price)
1,  2015-04-07 15:43:02,    230     230
2,  2015-04-07 15:44:04,    205     230
3,  2015-04-07 15:46:11,    220     230
4,  2015-04-07 15:48:01,    210     230
5,  2015-04-07 15:52:09,    200     210
6,  2015-04-07 15:53:32,    220     220
7,  2015-04-07 15:54:12,    207     220
8,  2015-04-07 15:57:33,    218     220
9,  2015-04-07 16:01:26,    221     221
10, 2015-04-07 16:07:51,    210     210
```